# android draw.createfrompath returns null

Tags: android, image, url, drawable, internal-storage

I have an image file stores in internalstorage :

```
"file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/pdfthumbnail5/helloworld.jpg"
```

I have no problem open it with image viewer app so the file is not corrputed or not readable.

What I am trying to do is, i wanna draw this jpg as a thumbnail on my custom list view, i have all listview logic working fine (that s not the concern here) , each time when the app try to draw the image thumbnail, it complains the image file not exist, and i tried to inspect the value of this method:

```
private static Drawable getDrawableFromUrl(final String url) throws IOException {
        if (url.contains("http")){   //when intent access available
            return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream) new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), "name");
        } else {   // when there is no internet access
            return Drawable.createFromPath(url);
        }
    }
```

and it returns me null object for Drawable....
btw, ignore the 1st part `if` statement please please, this is for when the app has internet access, and it draws thumbnail without problem when it draws directly from url. the problem is , it doesnt draw thumbnail from local internalstorage jpg.

please help me with code example. thanks

Comment: Use `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` instead of net.url, and append your folder/fileName.

Comment: return Drawable.createFromPath(((java.io.InputStream) context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/pdfthumbnail5/helloworld.jpg");    u mean something like that?  could you give me an example plz

Comment: This is use to get the file path, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS represents the internal directory/folder where your saving the file, now just append pdfthumbnail5/helloworld.jpg after the path returned by the above code and pass where you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static Drawable getDrawableFromUrl(final String url, Context context) throws IOException {
        if (url.contains("http")){
            return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream) new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), "name");
        } else {
            return Drawable.createFromPath(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/pdfthumbnail5/helloworld.jpg").toString());
        }
    }
```

works!